# Codeigniter can't find controller function 404 not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a web application with Codeigniter. But I can't navigate through my pages. example : I want that the button in page employee_view navigates to employeecontroller/addEmployee. I searched like hours for it at internet/stackoverflow. Tried everything, had like 5 various error messages. I'm tired of searching and hope someone can help me :)

here is a pic of my workspace and code :

[image: Image Link here]

my routes. php :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'EmployeeController';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['EmployeeController/addEmployee'] = 'EmployeeController/addEmployee';
$route['EmployeeController/createEmployee'] = 'EmployeeController/createEmployee';
$route['EmployeeController'] = 'application/controllers/EmployeeController';
```

in config.php i got :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/BoMaTec_afstudeerproject/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

my ht.acces file : 
[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/euq2vk.png[/IMG]

Comment: Here is routing user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: In your `.htaccess` file is FOLDER_NAME written or actual directory name?

Comment: I don't know.. what do i need to write in the ht.acces file?

Comment: @belgiums this may help with your htaccess here https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that all off your controllers class and file names have the first letter as uppercase.

Answer (score 4):

I presume your using codeigniter 3.

On codeigniter 3 the controllers **class** and **file name** must have the **first letter as uppercase** and then the rest lower case.

If controller name is EmployeeController I would change the name

File name: **Employee_controller.php**

```
class Employee_controller extends CI_Controller {

}
```

Then on routes: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Note: the default controller must be in `application/controllers/Employee_controller.php` default_controller does not work with sub folders all other routes do though.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'employee_controller';
$route['employee/addEmployee'] 'employee_controller/addEmployee';
$route['employee/createEmployee'] = 'employee_controller/createEmployee';
$route['employee'] = 'employee_controller';
```

URL Example

```
http://localhost:8888/BoMaTec_afstudeerproject/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/employee
```

Or

```
http://localhost:8888/BoMaTec_afstudeerproject/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/index.php/employee
```

And on autoload most common helpers to use are

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'text');
```

Comment: file name should be "employee_controller.php"

Comment: @Tiger in codeigniter 3 first letter should be upper case for class and filename.

Comment: I am not so aware about CI 3.X version but I think in older version it start by small letter

Comment: I still get error : The requested URL /BoMaTec_afstudeerproject/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/employee_controller/addEmployee was not found on this server.

Comment: Try with index.php in url

Comment: my controllers are in my directory at location BoMaTec_afstudeerproject/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/application/controllers/

Do i need to add the application/controllers to the url in routes.php?

Comment: Make sure you have `index()` method in default controller.

Comment: I got that. It seems like i'm a bit further. My error now is : The requested URL /index.php/controllers/employee/addEmployee was not found on this server.

How do i get that index.php away?

Answer (score 2):

**Change this in `config.php`**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**In controller**

Filename - `employee.php`

inside that

```
<?php

    if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
        exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Employee extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            # code...
        }

        public function addEmployee()
        {
            # code...
        }

    }
```

and in `autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

and in `<form>` `action` should be

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>employee/addEmployee" method="post">

</form>
```

This will wok fine

**EDIT 01**

Place this in `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what in routes.php ? still get an error requested url not found

Comment: did u place .htaccess file ??

Comment: I added the .htaccess file in original question

Comment: still get the ' The requested URL /BoMaTec_afstudeerproject/CodeIgniter-3.0.1/Employeecontroller/addEmployee was not found on this server.' error -_-

Comment: remove all the routes in your routes file. just keep default rout only

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'Employeecontroller';

Comment: there is no controller call `Employeecontroller`. Chamge that to `$route['default_controller'] = 'employee';`

Comment: the weird thing is that the default controller works. It's just when i want to navigate to an other page it gives an error..

Answer (score 1):

The controller name should be like Employeecontroller as Class name cannot contain more than 1 uppercase letters.

And in your routes it should be :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'employeecontroller';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write:-

```
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo site_url("EmployeeController/addEmployee");? 
 >">
```

in this manner:

```
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo site_url();?>/Employee_controller/addEmployee">
```

and change the name from EmployeeController to Employee_controller.

This has helped me.